# Loading a Targa (TGA) into a HBITMAP Displays Incorrect Color

Tags: c++, winapi, bmp, tga

I'm attempting to load a TGA file into memory and convert it to a HBITMAP so that I can draw it to the screen.

I'm having a problem where the colours that I see are not the same as the original TGA file.

I've double checked the file to ensure the correct one is being loaded, I've also double checked to ensure the TGA file is being loaded correctly into memory. I've also checked the TGA file with another program to see if it works and it does.

This is my code:

```
auto image = ReadImageFile("test.tga");
if (image == nullptr)
    break;

unsigned int displayWidth = 1920;
unsigned int displayHeight = 1080;

BITMAPINFO bmi = {};
bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = image->GetWidth();
bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -static_cast<int>(image->GetHeight());
bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(hdcMem, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, NULL, NULL, 0);
if (hBitmap) {
    SetDIBits(hdcMem, hBitmap, 0, image->GetHeight(), image->GetPixels(), &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);

    SetStretchBltMode(hdc, HALFTONE);
    StretchBlt(hdc, 0, 0, displayWidth, displayHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, image->GetWidth(), image->GetHeight(), SRCCOPY);

    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
}

DeleteDC(hdcMem);
EndPaint(pEventRecord->hWnd, &ps);
break;
```

Here are the properties of my TGA file:

```
Faces: 1
Pixel/Row Stride: 3
Mipmap Levels: 1
Image Width: 1920
Image Height: 1080
Bits Per Pixel: 24
Format: RGB
No Transparency
```

If I'm unable to resolve this then I am also open to using another approach to quickly load and display a TGA file.

Thank you.

Comment: `StretchBlt()` doesn't preserve colors. If you need a 1:1 copy use `BitBlt()` instead. Though it's unclear where you're even using your source `image`.

Comment: Where is `ReadImageFile` defined? What pixel format does `image->GetPixels()` return? When you inspect the bytes returned by `GetPixels()`, are they in BGR8 format?

Comment: You probably want COLORONCOLOR instead of HALFTOINE.  But, IInspectable is right, you only need BitBlt().  Describe the "wrong colors", is it multicolor "snow", or is it the wrong hue (RGB swapped)?

Comment: I've tried to BitBlt and using a different stretch mode too. but the result is the same. It seems it has the wrong hue. Although I thought the GetPixels function was returning the correct format, it wasn't. I followed the advice from Raymond to double check the format and that was indeed the problem. Thank you.